managedSourceDirectories compilation order in a Scala/Java project when upgrading to Scala 3
We've recently upgraded to Play Version 3.0.5, running Java 21.0.4, sbt version 1.10.3, with scalaVersion 2.13.14. Everything compiles and runs correctly with these versions when running sbt clean compile, but I end up with scalac compiler errors if I change the scalaVersion to 3.3.3.
The problem is that there is a part of our build that uses our custom annotation processor (called Carbide) to create methods for DAO calls, etc. that we manage. Here is the relevant part of our build.sbt:
Compile / compile := (Compile / compile dependsOn Def.task({
  (Compile / managedSourceDirectories).value.head.mkdirs()
})).value,
Compile / javacOptions ++= Seq("-s", (Compile / managedSourceDirectories).value.head.getAbsolutePath)

Carbide scans our entity classes for the @Entity annotation and then reflectively builds query methods associated with the members of each entity class. It is a seperate maven project we package as a jar in our app/lib.
With scala 3.3.3., our target/scala-3.3.3/src_managed/main/ directory is always built (and is empty), but we never make it past the scalac compile step, so our javacOptions are never actually run (since the javac part of the build is never invoked).
The errors we get from the scala compiler after running sbt clean compile are of this form:
[error] -- [E008] Not Found Error:.../DefaultCompetitionYearResource.java:8:39
[error] 8 |import shared.models.core.querybuilder.CompetitionYearQueryBuilder;
[error]   |                                       ^
[error]   |                  value querybuilder is not a member of shared.models.core

The queryBuilder source should end up in our target/scala-3.3.3/src_managed/main/ directory (and is built by our annotation processor), but for some reason, scalac in scala 3.3.3 is looking through our Java files before the src_managed sources are built (it seems). We need to keep our compileOrder := CompileOrder.Mixed because our scala and Java files rely on each other (for enabling route interaction in scala files, etc.).
These querybuilder classes are typically built after the scala compile is finished but before the main java compile begins. Here is a snippet of a successful sbt clean compile debug log with scala 2.13.14.
[debug] Scala compilation took 2.762843833 s
[debug] Attempting to call com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool@2137f8f8 directly...
[info] Annotation processing is enabled because one or more processors were found
[querybuilders are put into src_managed dir]
[info] Carbide warning: Unknown type: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode - skipping field: MasterSurveySchedule.template [These warnings are expected and okay]
[info] Carbide warning: Unknown type: byte[] - skipping field: ResourceBlob.resourceFile
[info] /Users/jludy/shared/app/shared/models/core/UnitTagGroup.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[debug] Java compilation took 11.978637459 s
[debug] [zinc] classfile.Parser parsing shared.models.core.querybuilder.support.DefaultAccountResolutionTypeQueryBuilderNode
[classfile.Parser then looks at all our java classses]
....
[debug] Java compilation + analysis took 14.683763333 s
[debug] done compiling
[debug] Registering generated classes:
[debug]     SsoRequireSetting$2.class
[debug]     Exceptions$FillRecursionException.class
[Then the rest are registered]
....


I have tried compiling JavaThenScala and ScalaThenJava, but neither of these options work (since our mixed build depends on each other). I have also tried upgrading to a different version of Scala, but anything stable after 3.3.0 breaks in the same way. I was expecting that there would be a way to either:

Compile our src_managed sources before the scala compiler runs
Somehow force the scala compiler to not look at Java classes affiliated with our queryBuilders


Where/when/how are your src_managed files supposed to be created?

I've updated the question with more context
